# How to make a deployable war file of a mule ESB application

Tags: mule

can somebody please help me how to make a war of a simple mule application.
My mule application consists of a single mule-config.xml file.
I have made this mule project in ecplise and can run it as a mule server.
My requirement is to make a war and deploy it in a tomcat or tcat server.

Thanks and Regards,
Arijit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [explained in the user guide](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Embedding+Mule+in+a+Java+Application+or+Webapp#EmbeddingMuleinaJavaApplicationorWebapp-EmbeddingMuleinaWebapp):

> To embed Mule inside a webapp, you provide one or more configuration file locations as context params and include a context listener to initialize the Mule Server.

So just add this in your web.xml, with mule-config.xml at the root of your classpath (for ex. in src/main/resources):

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.mule.config</param-name>
  <param-value>mule-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**EDIT** I've open-sourced a running demo: https://github.com/ddossot/mule-webapp-example