# Mule application into a deployable WAR

Tags: mule

How the Mule application can be directly convert into a war file, to deploy in Jboss application server, i tried and failed with creating the war file manually as mentioned [here](http://somaniab.blogspot.in/2012/12/steps-to-deploy-mule-esb-application-on.html) and gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648001/how-to-make-a-deployable-war-file-of-a-mule-esb-application) too, but still didn't get a clear view on this part.Provide a assistance with example. Note: there is no Mule-config.xml file in my sample mule application program

Comment: i m very fresh to mule, need the assistance to move further. thanks in advance

Comment: Share what errors are you getting with the app you tried to create.

Comment: Is your Maven project packaging set to 'war'? What's the Mule configuration file name(s)? Also share your `web.xml` config.

Comment: hi all, i couldn't able to create the war that is my main issue.. @David Dossot, there is no web.xml file in my mule Project.How to start creating war from scratch plz assist.I have installed maven plugin, but created a project as Mule project, do i need change the Project type also?

Comment: @Seba, Mule Project works fine while run in Mule ESB, now how can i convert it into deploy-able file for Jboss.

Comment: It's not really "convertible". You can probably reuse much of the logic, but you need to remake the project structure and test it again as things work a bit different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- In the `pom.xml`, ensure you have `<packaging>war</packaging>`
- Create `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` using the template below, replacing `YOUR_CONFIGS` with a comma-separated list of Mule configurations and `YOUR_PATH` with the path you want for the Mule servlet,
- Replace all your inbound HTTP endpoints with Servlet endpoints, like `<servlet:inbound-endpoint path="/YOUR_ENDPOINT_PATH" />`

And you should be good to go!

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.mule.config</param-name>
        <param-value>YOUR_CONFIGS</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>muleServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleReceiverServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>muleServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/YOUR_PATH/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**EDIT** I've open-sourced a running demo: https://github.com/ddossot/mule-webapp-example

Comment: thanks @David Dossot .. May i how to deploy mule project (with out maven) directly into Mule standalone runtime. Is there any Deploy folder like Jboss, before this process do i need to build the Mule project in specific format, plz assist..

Comment: That's a completely different question you're asking here, which is not great to do in a comment. You should use Maven to package an Mule application (packaging = mule) into a deployable ZIP that you then drop in MULE_HOME/apps (the deploy folder of Mule standalone). If you persist in not using Maven, you'll have to build a ZIP that follows this format: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Application+Format

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the required steps:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deploying+Mule+to+JBoss