# MuleStudio - packaging mule project as web app (WAR)

Tags: maven, mule, mule-studio

I created a standard mule project in Mule Studio, but I want to -

1. package app as standalone ZIP for local testing.
2. package app as WAR file deployable in tomcat.

The app doesn't have any HTTP endpoints, so there is no concern for changing HTTP to Servlet endpoint.

Does mule studio come with some out of the box options to generate WAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Studio has no facility for that. You could use Maven for that.

Also I'm assuming you've read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859119/387927