# Deploying Mule to Tomcat

Tags: mule, mule-studio

i'm very new to mule esb. I have some question after try mule.

1.how can i run mule project by Tomcat? (I've try this issue but seem not working : http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deploying+Mule+as+a+Service+to+Tomcat)
I have error when I starting tomcat like something was wrong.

2.How can I packing mule project to .war? ,I see that my editor(sts) don't think that mule application is a web application but the file path of mule application seem to be similar to maven generate project so... I don't know.

I use mule version 3.4.0

thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use the Mule Standalone, if you can. If you really need to use Tomcat, I suggest you package all the Mule dependencies into the application war with Maven, and not try to work with the jars manually. See the answer by David Dossot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831012/mule-application-into-a-deployable-war) and an example Maven project [here](http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2011/07/29/mule-esb-building-a-self-contained-standalone-web-app-with-maven/). Note that the example project uses Mule 3.1.2, so you probably want to update it a bit.

Comment: thank you Anton,that two link work very well!. And could you tell me why I should use Mule Standalone?

Comment: Less resources required, often best performance, less hassle... People usually use a separate application server only if their company's policy or infra team requires them to.

Comment: It depends what you're doing.  Read a comprehensive break down here https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/mule-versus-web-application-server