# mule maven application on tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, mule, mule-studio

I am using eclipse mars with mule 3.7.3 and java8. I want to create a sample mule flow and need a war file to deploy it on tomcat. 
this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.zz</groupId>
<artifactId>sample</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>mule</packaging>
<name>Mule sample Application</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <mule.version>3.7.3</mule.version>
    <mule.tools.version>1.1</mule.tools.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-resource</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>mappings/</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- Mule Dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- Xml configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Xml configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mule Transports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mule Modules -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>Central</id>
        <name>Central</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mulesoft-release</id>
        <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

This is my flow xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="sampleFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="HELLO SAMPLE"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

What changes should i make in my pom.xml so that i can get war file after maven build?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate question. You can refer to this one:

[Mule application into a deployable WAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831012/mule-application-into-a-deployable-war)

You can do the same procedure with Tomcat. Once the war is generated, you can deploy it.

Hope this helps.